# ReactJs props returns undefined in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have a problem with my props.

in my class, if I do :

```
<Input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" value={this.props.user.firstName}/>
```

that is working, my firstName appears.

but if I try :

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    console.log("firstName : "+this.props.user.firstName)
 }
```

that returns me `undefined`,  can someone help me ?

Comment: You aren't passing in any prop called `user`. You are passing in the `this.props.user.firstName` value into a prop called `value` from the parent component. Try using `this.props.value` instead https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps()` is deprecated, please avoid using it or add `unsafe_`.

Comment: you question title about componentDidMount but you use componentWillReceiveProps in your example

Comment: I tried with some other method and I forgot to change it before posting my question, sorry. but I tried with componentDidMount before

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, `componentWillReceiveProps` has been deprecated. So you might want to add `UNSAFE_` to the method name. Note from [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops):

> Note
>
> This lifecycle was previously named componentWillReceiveProps. That
>   name will continue to work until version 17. Use the
>   rename-unsafe-lifecycles codemod to automatically update your
>   components.

Second, you don't define lifecycle methods as arrow functions. You do it like this:

```
UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log("firstName : " + this.props.user.firstName)
}
```

Best solution? This:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.user !== this.props.user) {
    console.log(`firstName: ${this.props.user.firstName}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried with some other method and I forgot to change it before posting my question,that's why it was componentWillReceiveProps and not didMount, sorry. but your solution is working, thank you !